# How can I upload A file to shared folder in my google drive? {python}

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have tried almost everything on google documentation and almost all the possibilities I could explore by myself. I still cant file a viable solution.

I just need to create a program which uploads a given file for example "test.zip" in my working directory to google drive.

I have a client_secret.json but none of the solutions actually help online as I am having issues with authentication.

```
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "client_secret.json"
API_NAME = "drive"
API_VERSION = "v3"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]


service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,API_NAME,API_VERSION,SCOPES)

folder_id = "1QpsQB_R7JyqxueQwIe8_AvKGm7a25IoJ"
file_names = ["my_file.zip"]
mime_types = ['application/zip']

for file_name , mime_type in zip(file_names , mime_types):
  file_metadata = {
    "name" : file_name,
    "parents" : [folder_id]
  }
  media = MediaFileUpload('./Uploads/{0}'.format(file_name), mimetype=mime_type)
  service.files().create(
    body = file_metadata,
    media_body = media,
    fields = "id"
  ).execute()
```

this is the code I am using right now,

Create_service is being taken from google.py

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

but even after allowing authentication it shows,
[image]

any help will be appreciation :)

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]  If as you said "you have tried everything" please show us something.

Comment: i wd love to start with with minimal reproducible example

Comment: Great edit your question and show me your  code so i can have a look.

Comment: @DaImTo updated the question, if u please check it now

Comment: I think your missing some of your code theres nothing in your code that would result in "please visit this url to authorize this app"   Where's the rest of your code.  I need a [example] to test.   Have you tried following [offical example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#python)

Comment: the rest of the code goes into google.py updated the answer accordingly :)

Comment: @muzaaf nameer firdausi,  have you try to paste the URL in a browser, it should ask you to authenticate there. If I'm not mistaken it will provide you an ID or code to paste in terminal.  I think is doing this since you are using  `run_local_server()`.

Comment: Also did you name the token file downloaded from the GCP console `client_secret_file`? Also, can you try to changing the code from `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file` to `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file.json`